# running android dx quits batch script

Tags: android, batch-file

I am trying to build Android apps directly from the command line without using any build systems such as Gradle.

I wrote a small batch program which will do all the basic tasks required to build the apk file from the source code. This is my batch file :

```
@echo off
set /P build_tools_version="Enter build tools version : "
set /P android_version="Enter Android version : "
set /P package="Enter package name : "

%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools\%build_tools_version%\aapt      package -f -m -J %cd%\src -M %cd%\AndroidManifest.xml -S %cd%\res -I %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platforms\android-%android_version%\android.jar
echo aapt
javac -d %cd%\obj -source 1.8 -target 1.8 -classpath %cd%\src -bootclasspath %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platforms\android-%android_version%\android.jar %cd%\src\%package:.=\%\*.java
echo javac
%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools\%build_tools_version%\dx        --dex --output=%cd%\classes.dex %cd%\obj
echo dx
```

Where `%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%` points to the Android SDK directory.

When I am running this script, it is getting executed up to the `dx` command. The echo statement and the commands thereafter the `dx` command are not getting executed.
What mistake am I doing?

Comment: More information would have been helpful, instead of pointless code, _(now removed)_. Does it output `aapt`, and `javac`, but not `dx`? or just `aapt`?

Comment: It outputs `aapt` and `javac`, but not `dx`.

Comment: Well you've already been told why, and that's because `%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools\%build_tools_version%\dx` is really `%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools\%build_tools_version%\dx.bat`, which means that you need to `Call` it, if you want control to return back to the initiating batch file upon completion. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `call /?` to read its usage information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch script has an obvious issue:

These `echo` statements are useless, because the variables were never `set`.

On Windows, this should be `aapt.exe` / `aapt2.exe`, `javac.exe` and `dx.bat` / `d8.bat`.

You should at least define the variables, which you use:

```
set javac=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac.exe
set aapt=%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools\%build_tools_version%\aapt.exe
set aapt2=%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools\%build_tools_version%\aapt2.exe
set dx=%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools\%build_tools_version%\dx.bat
set d8=%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools\%build_tools_version%\d8.bat
```

In order to call `.bat` from `.bat`, you need to use `call`.

Removing `@echo off` might be useful for debugging.

Comment: Those `echo` statements are just for testing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used `call` command to run the `dx.bat` and it worked.